# Are data encryption ideas for PICs on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Let's say I have a PIC and an EEPROM memory IC. I store sensitive data in the EEPROM. If I want to encrypt the data, should I post it on EE or on [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) as a request for a fast and low memory cost encryption?

Comment: Interesting question, there are quite a few algorithm style questions where the traditional approaches aren't practical on some smaller microcontrollers.

Comment: A robust encryption algorithm with a poor implementation is ... a waste of time, to say the least. If you are concerned about proper data encryption, then talk to security professionals. Or even better encryption professionals, it is a profession on its own and with approximately 6 billion people on this globe, there are only very few that really understand all aspects. Bruce Schneier wrote truckloads of articles about good/bad practices in encryption (and information security). Check his website: http://www.schneier.com/

Comment: So You'd say I should've gone to the Cryptography section because the security profs are there? (and nice link!)

Comment: I think you need both. It entirely depends on the problem you want to solve. Security is always a fine balance between cost of implementation and cost when it gets compromised (in this case when clear text data is getting exposed). Along the same lines of course is how much money someone else can make with your compromised data.

Comment: There are many ways to protect electronically stored data, most of the time a combination is used in an end product. Don't store data that isn't strictly required (like the keys), use a proper algorithm, prevent physical access, ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I say EE is the place! Since the hardest (or at least the most complex part) of encrypting/decrypting a PIC's memory is in the implementation/access (as compared to encrypting some data in an asp.net environment.)

Plus, this site doesn't get enough cool questions! :-) and I'm not a member of cryptography...

Comment: Okay! :-) well here it is: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56482/encrypt-sensitive-data-in-eeprom